# slim framework Page not Found

Tags: php, apache, slim

i don't understand, that's not the first time i launch a project under slim but i have an unexplained error.

My folder:

```
c:\wamp\www\slim
```

I created "public" folder

```
c:\wamp\www\slim\public
```

Like the doc say, i create 2 .htaccess:
In root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

In public folder:

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And here my index.php in public folder:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
var_dump($_SERVER);

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
$response->getBody()->write("Hello");

return $response;
});

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
$name = $args['name'];
$response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

if i try to go to: http://localhost/slim/ :: Page not found
if i try to go to: http://localhost/slim/hello/Alex :: Page not found

It only works if i set my routes like this:

```
$app->get('/slim/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {...
```

I have to add "slim/" in route.

Why? On my other computer it works. The only thing that change is the version of apache: 2.3.4 and 2.3.23 Please help.

Comment: if you add a file to `c:\wamp\www` can you access it on localhost?

Comment: @AlexanderHolman yes i can access it by http://localhost/myfile.php

Comment: is it the exact same code as the working version? you didn't group your messages e.g. https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/add-prefix-to-all-routes/515/4 or https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#route-groups

Comment: @AlexanderHolman yes the code i posted is the same on my local computer. I do not know we can do that with slim, it's interesting.

Comment: in my index.php file in public folder, if i add this line: var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); it display: string 'C:/wamp/www/' (length=12)

Comment: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1529#issuecomment-341734546 seems to offer a fix, you didn't do something similar to this on your other laptop?

Comment: You're absolutly right! That's what i did on the other project (copy/paste from a blog). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that you add a file to c:\wamp\www can you access it on localhost, if you can't there is an issue with your configuration.

check that both versions are the exact code, one isn't using groups to wrap routes as they do in either of these: discourse.slimframework.com/t/add-prefix-to-all-routes/515/4 or slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#route-groups

Not using groups and want to support Slim from a subdirectory: Follow the steps described in this issue comment to github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1529#issuecomment-341734546 .